# Why do I have to cast an inherited class when it's proven that it is the base class?

Tags: c#, casting

I have a class called `BonusCell`. It inherits the `GameEntity` class.

```
public class BonusCell : GameEntity
{
   public void GiveStats()
   {

   }
}
```

I have a class called `Cell`

```
public Cell
{
    public GameEntity gameEntity;
}
```

I have a game grid that has a 2 dimension array of `Cell`.

```
public class Board
{
    public Cell[,] grid;
}
```

Why do I have to cast `BonusCell` even if I am using an `if is` statement to verify that it is a `BonusCell`? I understand that `board.grid[x,y].gameEntity` is a type of `GameEntity`, but if that's true how can it also be true that it `is BonusCell` ?

```
if (board.grid[x, y].gameEntity is BonusCell)
{
     BonusCell bonusCell = (BonusCell)board.grid[x, y].gameEntity;
     bonusCell.GiveStats();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do I have to cast BonusCell even if I am using an if is statement to verify that it is a BonusCell?

Because the `is` operator doesn't change the compile-time type of the expression `board.grid[x, y].gameEntity`. (In this case, I guess it's possible that a different thread could even change the value of `board.grid[x, y].gameEntity` between evaluations, making it genuinely unsafe. Either way, the compiler doesn't try to infer anything from the `if` condition. If the language specification required this, it would make it much more complicated.)

An alternative approach is to use `as` and an extra local variable :

```
BonusCell bonusCell = board.grid[x, y].gameEntity as BonusCell;
if (bonusCell != null) 
{
    bonusCell.GiveStats();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

`gameEntity is BonusCell` is just a check that returns a Boolean. The compiler makes no further assumptions about it. Even although you enter a conditional block of code on the back of `gameEntity` always being a `BonusCell` the compiler does not care. You then have to cast to `BonusCell` because as far as the compiler is concerned, you've only asked for a `GameEntity`.

Answer (score 1):

The 'is' operator only checks if the type you specify implements or extends another type.

Because GameEntity can be a base class for many types, you must check that the instance currently referenced is a BonusCell, this way you know you can cast it as BonusCell to access BonusCell specific members.

If you want only to access member of GameEntity a cast of is check is not necessary.

You can use the 'as' operator to cast and check if the instance is a BonusCell

```
BonusCell bonusCell;
if((bonusCell = board.grid[x, y].gameEntity as BonusCell) != null)
{
      bonusCell.GiveStats();
}
```